# Deriving MLEs for $\sigma_{\epsilon}^2$, $\beta$, and $Q$ in a Linear Mixed Model

Tags: mixed-model, maximum-likelihood, linear-model

I'm currently working on a problem involving a linear mixed model of the form:

$Y_i = X_i \beta + Z_i b_i + \epsilon_i,$

where $\epsilon_i \sim N (0, \sigma_{\epsilon}^2 I_{Ji})$. The model can also be represented as:

$V_i = Z_i GZ_i^T + \sigma_{\epsilon}^2 I_{Ji} = \sigma_{\epsilon}^2 (I_{Ji} + Z_i QZ_i^T),$

with $Q = G/\sigma_{\epsilon}^2$.

I'm trying to derive:

a. An explicit expression for the maximum likelihood estimate $\hat{\sigma}_{\epsilon}^2$ of $\sigma_{\epsilon}^2$ in terms of $\beta$ and $Q$.

b. An objective function for $\hat{\beta}$ and $\hat{Q}$ that is free of $\sigma_{\epsilon}^2$, using the expression for $\hat{\sigma}_{\epsilon}^2$ in the log-likelihood (profile likelihood).

c. Show that the maximum likelihood estimate of $\beta$ satisfies:

$\hat{\beta} = \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^T H_i^{-1} X_i \right)^{-1} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^T H_i^{-1} Y_i \right),$

where $H_i = (I_{Ji} + Z_i QZ_i^T)$.

I've tried re-expressing the likelihood function in terms of $Q$ and $\sigma_{\epsilon}^2$, considering the reparameterization, but I'm unsure how to proceed with the explicit derivations.

Could anyone guide me through the derivations or provide insights into tackling these questions? Any references to similar examples or literature would also be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hello David. What is the [Likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function) of on observation? Then modify it to likelihood of observing all your observations. You should then be able to differentiate with respect to your parameters to get estimators based on [maximum likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation).